# What is needed for MS Access to reuse the connection provided by a C# dll?

Tags: c#, oracle, dll, odbc, ms-access-2013

Dear

**Can someone please tell me what is needed for MS Access to reuse the connection provided by a C# dll ?**

We try to build a C# dll in the .NET Framework v4.0.30319.
This dll should provide a connection that is reused by our MS Access linked tables. 
We manage to set up connections to the Oracle DB, but MS Access doesn't use the connection for its' linked tables.
The overall set up is like this :
1. We have an Access 2013 database, that contains linked tables to an Oracle database.
2. These tables are linked via an ODBC User DSN, which is created as MYDSNNAME.
3. In the MS Access database, there is a reference to the above mentioned dll.
 
4. By calling the 'connect' function from the dll, a connection towards the Oracle dabatase is opened, using the credentials of the user.
5. Once the connection is open, MS Access should reuse the connection and the user can open the linked tables and pass-through queries that are available in the Access file.

[image: image of Schema]
Coding that is used :

1. Linked tables connectionstring :

```
ODBC;DSN=MYDSNNAME;DBQ=MyOracleDB;DBA=W;APA=T;EXC=F;FEN=T;QTO=F;FRC=10;FDL=10;LO=T;
RST=T;BTD=F;BNF=F;BAM=IfAllSuccessful;NUM=NLS;DPM=F;MTS=T;MDI=F;CSR=F;FWC=F;FBS=64000;
TLO=O;MLD=0;ODA=F;;TABLE=ORACLE_TABLE_NAME
```

2. C# dll code snippet :

```cs
// Ole DB 
public System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection cnOleDb;
public Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection cnOracleDataAccess;
public Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection cndevArt;
string sConnect = "Provider=MSDAora.1;Password=strong_password;
User ID=strong userid;
Data Source=<MyOracleDB>;Persist Security Info=true";
cnOleDb = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(sConnect);
sConnect = "Password=strong_password;User ID=strong userid;
Data Source=MyOracleDB;Persist Security Info=true";
cnOracleDataAccess = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(sConnect);
cndevArt = new Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection(sConnect);
cnOleDb.Open();
cnOracleDataAccess.Open();
cndevArt.Open();
//ODBC
string wConnect = "DSN=MYDSNNAME;UID=strong_ID;PWD=strong_PWD";
cnODBC = new OdbcConnection(wConnect);
cnODBC.Open();
```

Thanks for your input !

Comment: Any error messages? What is the actual problem?

Comment: Why do you use so many different connection types?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to establish a connection using an external DLL? Is it simply to hide the login credentials?

Comment: @LucMorin : There are no error messages. The point is that the linked tables in MS Access should use the connection/credentials that are provided by the dll to connect to the Oracle db.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : The code snippet above shows all connections I have been trying so far. In practice I should come to one connection that does the job.

Comment: @GordThompson Originally, this was an VB6 OCX, it provides a Login OCX that allows the user to enter his credentilals, then does a check on the password to be compliant with the companies login policies. When all conditions are met, a connection is set up to the Oracle db, and this connection is the reused by the linked tables and the pass-trough queries of the MS Access application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to use a connection from a .NET assembly directly to link a table. However it should be possible to use it in a VBA Macro, perhaps you can build the linked tables by a macro. I am not familiar with MS Access but the code may look like this (not tested):

C#:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class MyClass {


[ComVisible(true)]
public OracleConnection GetConnection(){

   var connectString = "Data Source=MYDSNNAME;User ID=strong_ID; Password=strong_PWD";
   var con = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(connectString);
   con.Open();
   return con;
}

}
```

VBA Macro:

```
Set obj = CreateObject("MyClass")
Set conn = obj.GetConnection()

... use conn object
```

Have also a look at these resources:

[Best Practice in Writing a COM-Visible Assembly](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/612604/Best-Practice-in-Writing-a-COM-Visible-Assembly-Cs)

[Exposing .NET Components to COM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3511/Exposing-NET-Components-to-COM)

Comment: Hello Wernfried, thanks for your input. Your response is very much appreciated and the links are very helpful in getting started with COM operability from C# dll's. However, I tried to implement the code as described above, and it doesn't solve the issue.